# How to make android application as preinstall application?

Tags: android, system

i am using the command `adb push 'application_name.apk'  /system/app/` . this command push the apk in the `/system/app/`  folder of emulator  from my computer directory . and an icon is created on the application display screen with other apps .

and when i reboot the emulator , i found no icon of the app on the app display screen.

what does it mean ?  (can i assume that this application does not install or `adb push` command only put the `apk` in  the `/system/app/` directory ).

for installing that application we have to manually install the application from the `/system/app/` manually as we install other `apk`  from `sdcard` . )

Comment: If you want to pre-install your app after reboot then you have to customize Android OS as per your need. In all other cases you have to manually install it.

Comment: I think this question belongs on [Android Enthusiasts](http://android.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: i am using the android emulator . and in emulator i have super user rights . so you mean in the emulator after pusing in the directory /system/app/ i have to manually install the apk to make it preinstall application.

Comment: @Tauqir    i am using the android emulator . and in emulator i have super user rights . so you mean in the emulator after pusing in the directory /system/app/ i have to manually install the apk to make it preinstall application.